# Using memcpy to copy a range of elements from an array

Tags: c++, memcpy

Say we have two arrays:

```
double *matrix=new double[100];
double *array=new double[10];
```

And we want to copy 10 elements from matrix[80:89] to array using `memcpy`.

Any quick solutions?

Comment: would that code compile?

Comment: I think that's not even a valid c++ declaration of an array. memcpy requires a start and a length + size of the variable. The Parameters have to be something like matrix = src, array = dest, 80 = start, 10 = len, sizeof(double) = size . $ man memcopy

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `double matrix[100];` and `double array[10];`?

Comment: yeah...that code doesn't look right in any language..

Comment: @original poster: if you correct the sample code i'll bump the points back - the answers are useful enough; the question is misleading though (incorrect code)

Answer (score 25):

It's simpler to use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(matrix + 80, matrix + 90, array);
```

This is cleaner because you only have to specify the range of elements to be copied, not the number of bytes.  In addition, it works for all types that can be copied, not just POD types.

Answer (score 16):

```
memcpy(array, &matrix[80], 10*sizeof(double));
```

But (since you say C++) you'll have better type safety using a C++ function rather than old C `memcpy`:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::copy(&matrix[80], &matrix[90], array);
```

Note that the function takes a pointer "one-past-the-end" of the range you want to use.  Most STL functions work this way.

Comment: One advantage of using the `matrix + N` instead of `&matrix[N]` is that for an array of size `M`, `matrix + M` is allowed but `&matrix[M]` is not (because the latter dereferences a pointer to the element one-past-the-end).

Answer (score 11):

```
memcpy(array, matrix+80, sizeof(double) * 10);
```