# c++ creating a subarray from a duplicate array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

here is my code and im not allowed to use a loop in the subarray function im pretty confused maybe someone can point me in the right direction i feel like im almost there..

```
int *duplicateArray(int *arr, int size) 
{
int *newArray;

if (size<=0)
    return NULL;

newArray = new int[size];

for (int index=0;index<size;index++)
    newArray[index]=arr[index];

return newArray;
}

int* subArray(int *sub, int start, int length)
{

 int aa[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
 int *dup;
 dup = aa;
 duplicateArray(dup,10);
 return dup;


}

int main()
{   cout << "Testing subArray: " << endl 
         << "Expected result: 5, 6, 7, 8 " << endl;
int *subArr;
int start = 5;
subArr = subArray(subArr, 5,4);
for (int index = start; index<10; index++)
    cout << subArr[index];
delete [] subArr;
subArr = 0;
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3902230/1387612)

Comment: I guess that in `subArray` you want to call `duplicateArray` passing `sub+start` to represent the first element of the array to be copied, and `length` as the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since this is homework, I'm going to avoid posting a solution directly.  You say that;

> im not allowed to use a loop in the subarray function

Yet, currently, `subArray` calls `duplicateArray`, which uses a loop.  This seems to be in conflict with the spirit of the requirement.

Since you haven't said otherwise, I'm assuming that `subArray` should *duplicate* the contents of its argument between `start` and the end.  So, what do we know?

We know that the size of the returned array should be `length - start` elements.  We also know (well, perhaps) that a function named `memcpy` exists which allows you to copy a block of bytes from one place to another (assuming they do not overlap).

(note that I am suggesting `memcpy` here because we are dealing with POD types ([Plain Old Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)) and because I doubt your class has delved into the STL.  In the future you will be better served by something like `std::copy()`, but for now this is ok)

So, in order, we need to:

1. Declare a new array to return with `length - start` elements. *You must dynamically allocate this array*!  Currently you are returning a pointer to a locally declared array. That pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.
2. Copy `length - start` elements (elements, not bytes!  Make sure to take into account the number of elements as well as the size of an individual element) from `sub + start` into this new array.
3. Return the new array (pointer really).

If I have somehow violated the requirements or intent of your assignment then you need to elaborate on your problem for me.  Currently there is not much to go on.