# Copying a single array to a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, .net, arrays, command-line-interface, sorting

I have declared the following two arrays.
One is a single array of 4 elements, The other is a multidimensional array of 5 rows and 4 colums (see diagram below).

```
array<String^> ^single_row = {"E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"};
array<String^,2>^ multi_row=gcnew array<String^,2>(5,4);
```

Is there built in function I can use to copy the first array let's say the third row of the second array, without manually copying each element?

Note: I've tried array->copy but experienced error C3262: invalid array indexing: 1 dimension(s) specified for 2-dimensional 'cli::array ^'
I've attached a diagrams to assist for visualisation purposes.
[image: Array diagrams]

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902215/using-memcpy-to-copy-a-range-of-elements-from-an-array

Comment: there is no memcpy for c++ clr though

Comment: maybe the way you use array->copy is incorrect. try something like Array::Copy(single_row,multi_row[3],4); specifying the row where to copy in multi_row

Comment: @stark This is not a duplicate. The link you have is of unmanaged c++ and the copy of a single arary.

Comment: @GeraldSv I get the following errors when trying Array::Copy(single_row,multi_row[3],4);

Error 1 error C3262: invalid array indexing: 1 dimension(s) specified for 2-dimensional 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'
Error 2 error C2665: 'System::Array::Copy' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any function to do this.
The only thing that I've found is that you can create the first array as multidimensional too.

```
array<String^,2> ^single_row = {{"E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"}};
array<String^,2>^ multi_row=gcnew array<String^,2>(5,4);
```

Then use:

```
Array::Copy(single_row,0,multi_row,2*4,4);
```

I hope this helps.

Kindest Regards

KooKoo